# Mandrill SMTP HTML template email send

Tags: php, mysql, mandrill

I am working with PHP

I am creating a a mail application that uses mandrill SMTP to send email. The application will allow users to select custom designed email templates that are stored on the DB as pure html code in tbl_template.

I have written a code that queries the database and fetches all the templates and stores them in html  tags for the user to select one.

I am facing two issues one of which is the whole Html code is visible within all the option tags.
2nd problem when I am not sure how to store the option value="" attribute (which stores all template html code) and save it into a $_SESSION or be able to use that value content as part of an email.

load_template.php:

> function LoadTemplate(){
>
> ```
> define('DB_HOST', "localhost");
> define('DB_USER', "root");
> define('DB_PASSWORD', "root");
> define('DB_NAME', "db_mailer");
> $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ("Cnnection Error".mysqli_error($con));
>
> $sql = "SELECT id, temp_name, temp_structure FROM tbl_template";
> $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
>     $option='<select name="template">';
>     $option.='<option name="temp">Select Template</option>';
>     $option.='';
>         while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
>             $option.='<option id="'.$result['id'].'" value="'.$result['temp_structure'].'">'.$result['temp_name'].'</option>';
>
>         }
>     $option.='</select>';
>
> return $option; }
> ```

index.php:

> Your email:
>
> ```
> <p>Your Name:<br>
>     <input type="text" id="from_name" name="from_name" placeholder="Please type in your email..."></p>
>
> <p>Send To Email:<br>
>     <input type="email" id="to_email" name="to_email" placeholder="Please type in the client email..."></p>
>
> <p>Send To name:<br>
>     <input type="text" id="to_name" name="to_name" placeholder="Please type in the client email..."></p>
>
> <p>Subject:<br>
>     <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Wright something nice..."></p>
>
>     <?php require('load_temp.php'); echo LoadTemplate(); ?>
>
> <p><textarea rows="5" cols="5"></textarea></p>
> <input type="submit" value="Send" name='submit'>
> ```

mail.php part of mandrill SMTP file that I have to just config:

```
> <?php /**  * Created by PhpStorm.  * User: MDuarte  * Date: 11/03/2014
> * Time: 10:28  */ $data=Array();
> 
> $data['from_email']= $_POST['from_email']; $data['from_name']=
> $_POST['from_email']; $data['to_email']= $_POST['to_email'];
> $data['to_name']= $_POST['to_name']; $data['subject'] =
> $_POST['subject']; $data['content'] = $_POST['template'];
> $data['temp'] = $_POST['template'];
> 
> require_once "Mandrill.php";
> 
> try {
>     $mandrill = new Mandrill('API_KEY');
>     $message = array(
>         'html' => $data['temp'],
>         'text' => 'Example text content',
>         'subject' => $data['subject'],
>         'from_email' => $data['from_email'],
>         'from_name' => $data['from_name'],
>         'to' => array(
>             array(
>                 'email' => $data['to_email'],
>                 'name' => $data['to_name'],
>                 'type' => 'to'
>             )
>         ),
> 
> } catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
>     // Mandrill errors are thrown as exceptions
>     echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
>     // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id >'customer-123'
>       throw $e; }
```

Now the email is send containing everything but not the html template, I am trying to add the html template in mail.php

> 'html' => $data['temp'],

Comment: Forgive me, but, I don't ever see you set the content type of the email to `text/html` and the default is `text/plain`. I've never used Mandrill, but I can assume it does not use html by default, unless it uses a switch case on the existence of that array key, but I have to doubt that.

Comment: the content type is set on the each email template its self, I managed to get it work but no matter which template I use it is always the last one send now, so i belief there is something wrong with my while loop each time the variable there is overwritten

Comment: in the first file load_temp.php.......

Comment: You should ask your users to provide a name for templates and first load these names in a drop-down. When a user selects a template name just load its html from database and use it.

Answer (score 0):

While sending html code through any mails. It converts them to html real tags.

So,

use `urlencode(YOUR HTML CONTENT)` to add the html template

have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

hope this helps.